# Set shortcut for ToggleEditing, save editing, Pan in QGIS python

Tags: pyqgis, editing

I need to write scripts to set shortcuts for Toggle Editing, Save Editing, and Pan. I am using QGIS 3.16. Here is the code I used to set shortcut for Toggle Editing, there is no errors when I run it. But it's not working

```
def Ed():
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    if not layer.isEditable():
        layer.startEditing()
        layer.commitChanges()
    else:
        layer.commitChanges()
        layer.stopEditing()
    
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QKeySequence
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QShortcut
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt
shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_E), iface.mainWindow())
shortcut.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
shortcut.activated.connect(Ed)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you call `layer.commitChanges()` immediately after `startEditing()` which, by default, finishes the editing command if the commit is successful. To avoid this behavior, you can pass a `False` argument which will keep the layer in edit mode or alternatively remove the command altogether. Additionally, this means that in your else clause, you don't need to call `stopEditing()`.

Working code:

```py
def Ed():
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    if not layer.isEditable():
        layer.startEditing()
        #line below is optional...
        #layer.commitChanges(False)
    else:
        layer.commitChanges()
    
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QKeySequence
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QShortcut
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt
shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_E), iface.mainWindow())
shortcut.setContext(Qt.ApplicationShortcut)
shortcut.activated.connect(Ed)
```